# Rails update form throwing "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create an update form on Rails, for an object that has a foreignkey to another. However, it throws this error. I'm still very greenhorn with Ruby on Rails and have just been following a video tutorial, so I'm not quite sure how to interpret this. I am current using rails 5.0.0

In `travelers_controllers.rb`, below line

```
@prf = update_prof_params["profiles_attributes"]["0"]
```

throws the error

> **undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass**

---

**edit.html.erb**

```
<div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-3 main">
  <% provide(:title, "Edit user")%>
  <center><h1>Update your profile</h1></center>
  <%= form_for(@person) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <%= render 'layouts/profilefields', f: f %>
      <%= f.submit "Save Changes", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**_profilefields.html.erb**

```
<%= f.fields_for :profiles do |prf|%>
  <!--
  <% if !@profileInfo["avatar"].blank? %>
    <%= image_tag @contactInfo.avatar_url(:medium).to_s, :class=>"profilePhoto" %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="photoPreview">
    <i class="fa fa-upload photoUpload"></i>
    <p id="uploadClick">Click to Upload</p>
  </div>

  <%= prf.file_field :avatar, accept: 'image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg, image/jpg', id: 'uploadAvatar' %>
  <p class="deletePhoto">Delete</p>
  -->

  <%= prf.label :about %>
  <%= prf.text_field :about, :class => "form-control" %>
  <%= prf.label :why %>
  <%= prf.text_field :why, :class => "form-control" %>
  <%= prf.label :goals %>
  <%= prf.text_field :goals, :class => "form-control" %>


  <%= prf.hidden_field :traveler_id, value: current_traveler.id %>
<% end %>
```

**travelers_controller.rb**

```
class TravelersController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @person = Traveler.find(params[:id])
    @profileInfo = Profile.find_or_initialize_by(traveler_id: params[:id])
    #@profileInfo[:email] = current_traveler.email

    #This builds the form
    @person.build_profile(@profileInfo.attributes)
  end

  def show
  end

  def update
    @prf = update_prof_params["profiles_attributes"]["0"]
    @prof = Profile.find_or_create_by(traveler_id: current_traveler.id)
    if @prof.update_attributes(prf) 
        flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
        redirect_to feed_path
      else # Failed. Re-render the page as unsucessful
        render :edit
    end
  end

  private 
    def update_prof_params
      params.require(:traveler).permit(profiles_attributes: [:about, :why, :goals,
          :traveler_id])
    end
end
```

and the **models**

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :traveler, foreign_key: "traveler_id"
end

class Traveler < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # , :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_one :profile
end
```

Comment: It is weird, what is your purpose running this `update_prof_params["profiles_attributes"]["0"]`?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not really quite sure. It was in a tutorial. I've tried ommitting it completely and changing it to  if @prof.update_attributes(update_prof_params) and that *submits* the form okay, but the problem then becomes the new values don't save and get updated in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TravelersController, the method `update` should be used for update traveler, not profile, so you can use mass-update via nested attribute like this:

```
def update
  @traveler = Traveler.find(params[:id])
  if @traveler.update(update_prof_params) 
    flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
    redirect_to feed_path
  else # Failed. Re-render the page as unsucessful
    render :edit
  end
end
```

So the above allow you to create/update profile which belongs to traveler. Besides, ensure the nested attribute was defined in your model:

**traveler.rb**

```
class Traveler < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Your code here
  #....

  # Make sure define this
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
end
```

## Update: The permitted params should be:

```
def update_prof_params
  params.require(:traveler).permit(profile_attributes: [:about, :why, :goals, :traveler_id])
end
```

As you see `profile_attributes` should be used instead of `profiles_attributes` because `traveler` has one `profile` only

Comment: I've tried this and it still does not update. The log on the console says "Unpermitted parameter: profiles" but I believe that should be taken care of with params.require(:traveler).permit(profiles_attributes: [:about, :why, :goals, :traveler_id])